# UWP with ReactiveUI: InteropServices error in deployed app and not locally (be it on Debug or Release mode)

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

My UWP is compiled on VS2017 asure pipelines hosted agents with .Net native compilation turned on. Once deployed, the app has a systematic crash. I use Raygun to log the exception.

Message:

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found. Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed(Int32, RuntimeTypeHandle) + 0x21:null
__Interop.ComCallHelpers.Call(__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32, Void*, Void*) + 0x48:null
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler__Impl.Invoke(__ComObject, Object, PropertyChangedEventArgs) + 0x9f:null
System.Action`2.InvokeClosedStaticThunk(T1, T2) + 0x2e:null
System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object, IntPtr, InvokeUtils.ArgSetupState&) + 0x62:null
System.InvokeUtils.CalliIntrinsics.Call(IntPtr, Object, Object, IntPtr, InvokeUtils.ArgSetupState&) + 0x43:null
System.InvokeUtils.CallDynamicInvokeMethod(Object, IntPtr, Object, IntPtr, IntPtr, Object, Object[], BinderBundle, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) + 0x12f:null
```

My main problem is that I am unable to reproduce the crash on my dev environement (VS2019), be it in debug or release mode.

I know the initial action that causes the crash but cannot see why it does.

I have a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyProject.Shared.Controls.Etablissements"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="using:MyProject.ViewModels.Interfaces"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:IMyControlViewModel}">

    <ComboBox Header="Item" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="ComboBox">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding Color}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

With code behind:

```
public new static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(IsEnabled),
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(true, OnIsEnabledChanged)
);

public new bool IsEnabled
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
}

private static void OnIsEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as MyControl ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
    control.ComboBox.IsEnabled = control.IsEnabled;
}
```

Then in constructor of the view model of a page that uses `MyControl` I have the following observable subscription that leads to the crash when `SomeId` (which is intially 0 by default) turns positive:

```
this
    .WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeId, id => id <= 0)
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Subscribe(isEnabled => MyControlViewModel.IsEnabled = isEnabled)
    .DisposeWith(Disposables);
```

Note that when I first experience that crash, the line `ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` was not there and while the initial error was the same in the log, it didn't stop there and on top of it there was the following error:

Message:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

StackTrace:

```
ReactiveUI.WeakEventManager`3.WeakHandlerList.DeliverEvent(Object, TEventArgs) + 0xfa:null
ReactiveUI.WeakEventManager`3.PrivateDeliverEvent(Object, TEventArgs) + 0x188:null
ReactiveUI.WeakEventManager`3.DeliverEvent(TEventSource, TEventArgs) + 0x220:null
ReactiveUI.ReactiveList`1.ReactiveUI.IReactiveObject.RaisePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs) + 0x18:null
ReactiveUI.IReactiveObjectExtensions.ExtensionState`1.raisePropertyChanged(String) + 0x8a:null
ReactiveUI.IReactiveObjectExtensions.raisePropertyChanged[TSender](TSender, String) + 0x15e:null
ReactiveUI.IReactiveObjectExtensions.RaiseAndSetIfChanged[TObj, TRet](TObj, TRet&, TRet, String) + 0x6e:null
MyProject.ViewModels.Controls.MyControlViewModel.set_IsEnabled(Boolean) + 0x29:null
MyProject.ViewModels.MyPageViewModel.<>c__DisplayClass79_0.<.ctor>b__26(Int64) + 0x21:null
```

Comment: Hi, I noticed that the binding method of your ComboBox's SelectedItem is set to TwoWay, is it caused by this problem? Try setting it to OneWay and running to see if it still crashes

Comment: It has to be TwoWay has the user selects an item in the combobox which in turns set the SelectedItem on the ViewModel. Btw, the combobox itself works well. The crash is when I try to disable it.

Comment: I tried to build a project to implement your UserControl, its IsEnabled property works fine, but I don't know if this is the way you write code. Can you put the minimum running code Post?

Comment: did you deploy the app? It does work fine on my machine either in debug / release mode. I don't understand why it doesn't once deployed. I can systematically reproduce the crash on deployed app but never on local app.

Comment: I think this may be the cause of the problem. I deployed the application. It works fine locally. You can try to use try-catch to locate the problem, generate the installation package and deploy debugging on other devices. But I still hope that you can provide the minimum running code so that I can help you better.

Comment: did you compile for .net native?

Comment: yes, it is. I am trying to compile a project using VS2017